# How to count number of (weakly) decreasing sequences of numbers?

Tags: algorithm, counting

I want to solve a problem without loops. Assume we have N place, and for each place you can select a number between [p,q] but the number in place i+1 should be less or equal than the number in place i. Now how to count all possible strings without brute force.

For example assume we have 2 places and you can select a number between [2,3] then the possible sequences can be:

3 3

3 2

2 2

As the number of places is not limited also the p an q then it is impossible to solve it with simple loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's choose(q-p+N, N) where choose is the binomial coefficient.

Weakly decreasing sequences that are between p and q are in bijection with sequences of 0's and 1's of length q-p+N, where the sequences have exactly N ones. It's obvious that the number of such sequences is choose(q-p+N, N) because that's the number of ways of choosing N things from q-p+N things.

### The proof that the two sets are in bijection

Given a sequence xs of 0's and 1's of length q-p+N with N 1's, this pseudocode generates a weakly decreasing sequence of numbers between p and q:

```
 c = q
 for x in xs
     if x = 1 then output c
     if x = 0 then c <- c - 1
```

Conversely, given an weakly decreasing sequence xs of length N between p and q, this pseudocode generates a sequence of 0's and 1's of length q-p+N with exactly N 1's.

```
 c = q
 while xs is not empty
     if c = head(hs) then
         output 1
         xs <- tail(xs)
     else
         output 0
         c <- c - 1
 while c > p
     output 0
     c <- c - 1
```

Here `head(xs)` denotes the first thing in the xs list, and `tail(xs)` the remainder of the list.

Comment: Dear Paul,

First of all thanks for the answer. But maybe I didn't explain well.
First of all the digits which can place in each place is from [p,q] and the problem is not to generate numbers between p and q.
For example assume we have 3 place and digits can be from [2,3] then the possible strings are:
3 3 3; 3 3 2; 3 2 2; 2 2 2
if the number could be from [1,3] then this list would be 10 items and if the places increases to 4 places and digits could be from [1,3] then the number of strings could be 15 :
3 3 3 3; 3 3 3 2; .....; 2 2 2 1; ....; 1 1 1 1

Comment: Second I just need the number of possible strings and not generating all possible strings and count number of them. That is brute force and I know how to generate all possible strings. Maybe some permutation formula can find this number.

Comment: @Majid Perhaps I didn't explain well (or perhaps you just skimmed and misread the answer), but I give an explicit formula for the number of solutions choose(q-p+N,N), and then my proof shows its correctness. The algorithms there describe the bijection, but those are part of a proof, not part of a program which enumerates sequences.

Comment: @PatriceGahide https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) is a good technique to know, and that was the basis for this answer.

Comment: @Paul Wooooow thanks. That works. Just 1 more question how about if change the condition to less instead of less and equal.
for example if we say the number in place i+1 must be less than number in place i?

Comment: @Majid it's choose(q-p+1, N)

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PaulHankin Just the last question. Is there any formula for a more general ones? For example if p and q are different for each place and also the relation between the places. For example for N=4 but with some p and q like following.
E.g. : [9,10] > [4,9] > [2,6] >= [2,6]